# `this` keyword equivalent in delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, function-calls

Let's say that we have this class:

```
unit Traitement;

interface

type
  TTraitement =class
  public        
    function func1(param:String): String;
    function func2(param:String): String;
  end;

implementation

function TTraitement.func1(param:String): String;
begin
  //some code
end;

function TTraitement.func2(param:String): String;
begin
  //some code
end;

end.
```

And I want to call `func1` in the code of `func2`. Well I used to be a Java programmer, and in this case I would use the keyword `this`. Does Pascal have an equivalent for the `this` keyword?  If not, how can I achieve this kind of call?

Comment: FWIW: You can just call it like `func1(...);` - no need for qualifying it with `Self`.

Comment: Note that `Self` in Object Pascal isn't really a **keyword**, but rather an **implicit variable**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent to Java's `this` in Delphi is [`Self`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Self). From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Self):

> ### Self
>
> Within the implementation of a method, the identifier Self references
>   the object in which the method is called. For example, here is the
>   implementation of TCollection Add method in the Classes unit:
>
> ```
> function TCollection.Add: TCollectionItem;
> begin
>   Result := FItemClass.Create(Self);
> end;
> ```
>
> The Add method calls the Create method in the class referenced by the
>   FItemClass field, which is always a TCollectionItem descendant.
>   TCollectionItem.Create takes a single parameter of type TCollection,
>   so Add passes it the TCollection instance object where Add is called.
>   This is illustrated in the following code:
>
> ```
>  var MyCollection: TCollection;
>  ...
>  MyCollection.Add   // MyCollection is passed to the 
>                     // TCollectionItem.Create method
> ```
>
> Self is useful for a variety of reasons. For example, a member
>   identifier declared in a class type might be redeclared in the block
>   of one of the class' methods. In this case, you can access the
>   original member identifier as Self.Identifier.

Note, however, that the example code in the question has no need to use `Self`. In that code you can call `func1` from `func2` omitting `Self`.

The example given in the above documentation excerpt does provide proper motivation for the existence of `Self`.